# Are Indexed Views slowing down write access to a table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have index view create a view on Table1 and Table2 and ID is the clustered in Table1

```
create view VwTestView
with schemabinding
as
Select t1.ID,t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col1,t2.col2 from from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on (t1.ID=t2.ID) 
go
create unique clustered index VwIX_ID on VwTestView (ID)
```

My question is,Is the index VwIX_ID on a view VwTestView will slowdown the insert/update/delete on table1 or table2

Comment: you should vote up useful answers and accept one. This is why we answer questions: for reputation.

Answer (score 1):

It's extra work for the database engine to maintain the indexed view. There is an impact but you'd have to measure on your system to see the increased work (eg via SQL profiler CPU and Writes columns)

Unless you have massive write volumes, it shouldn't matter because you'll probably gain a lot more from reads *if* they use the indexed view. The optimiser may ignore the indexed view of course unless you use NOEXPAND which is required on standard edition and obviously requires testing itself otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there will be a marginal impact on both tables, for all insert/update/delete statements. Just as there is an impact adding an index to any table. You don't get any indexing operations "for free".